# error: ‘row’ in namespace ‘pqxx’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, c++11, debian, libpqxx

I compiled my c++ program using libpqxx on my development machine.
but in deployment machine i got this error:
error: ‘row’ in namespace ‘pqxx’ does not name a type
i installed same version libpqxx on deployment machine.

```
boost::property_tree::ptree UserModel::GetUsersJson(int page, std::string query){
    pqxx::result R = GetUsers(page, query);
    int count = R.size();
    int pageCount = count / OFFSET_COUNT;
    boost::property_tree::ptree users_node;
    boost::property_tree::ptree user_node;
    for(pqxx::row r : R)
    {
        user_node.put("id", r[0]);
        user_node.put("email", r[1]);
        user_node.put("password", r[2]);
        user_node.put("details", r[3]);
        user_node.put("created_at", r[4]);
        users_node.push_back(std::make_pair(r[0].c_str(), user_node));
    }
    return users_node;
}
```

Comment: What version is that? I don't see any type `pqxx::row` in the v4 docs (http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/4.0/html/Reference/classes.html)

Comment: Why not use the provided type aliases (http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/4.0/html/Reference/a00082.html) or an `auto`?

Comment: libpqxx version 4.0.1

Comment: can you use `auto`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think find reason.
I downloaded pqxx source (ver 5) and compiled on my development machine and used some new features. and after that install libpqxx-dev (ver 4).
but on deployment machine only install libpqxx(ver 4).
this was my mistake.
thanks for very helpful comments.

Comment: So, in fact, it wasn't the same version :)

Comment: I see now that v5 introduced the `row` class (https://libpqxx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/a00080.html). Shame they changed the API so much. You'll have to be careful about that.